# Too simple proof for convergence of $\sum_n a_n b_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My question relates to Chapter 3, Exercise 8 in "Baby Rudin". It states:

***If* $\sum_n a_n$ *converges*, *and if* $\{b_n\}$ *is monotonic and bounded*, *prove that $\sum_n a_n b_n$ converges*.**

My attempt would have been:

*Since $\{b_n\}$ is monotonic and bounded, $\{b_n\}$ converges and it exists $\inf \{b_n\}$ as well as $\sup \{b_n\}$. But then we have
$$ \left| \sum_n a_n \inf \{b_n\} \right| \leq \left| \sum_n a_n b_n \right| \leq  \left| \sum_n a_n \sup \{b_n\} \right| \leq \max \left( \left| \sup \{b_n\} \right|, \left| \inf \{b_n \} \right| \right)\varepsilon \leq \tilde{\varepsilon} $$
since $\sum_n a_n$ converges and $\max \left( \left| \sup \{b_n\} \right|, \left| \inf \{b_n \} \right| \right)$ is a finite number. This would imply, by the comparison test, that $\sum_n a_n b_n$ converges as well. $\quad \Box$*

But as there was a way longer, more rigorous proof chosen in this [solution manual](http://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/67009), I'm a bit suspicious that my proof is not complete. Am I missing something?

---

EDIT: Thanks everyone! @hermes:

The last part of your proof gave me the following idea. As $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = c$ and $\{b_n\}$ is monotonic, couldn't we just set $b_n = c - c_n$ with a monotonically decreasing sequence $\{c_n\}$ which has $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0$. Then we have

$$\sum_n a_n b_n = \underbrace{c \sum_n a_n}_{\text{converges by assumption}} - \underbrace{\sum_n a_n c_n}_{\text{converges by Theorem 3.42}} \leq \varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon $$

since

---

**Theorem 3.42** Suppose

- the partial sums of $\sum_n a_n$ form a bounded space $\quad \checkmark$
- $c_0 \geq c_1 \geq c_2 \geq \dots \quad \checkmark$
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0 \quad \checkmark$

Then $\sum_n a_n c_n$ converges.

---

Thus $\sum_n a_n b_n$ converges as well. $\quad \Box$

Now that should hold, I think. So I wouldn't need to go through all the estimates.

Comment: Is the comparison test already treated in Chapter 3?

Comment: If the $a_n$ don't all have the same sign, your inequalities don't necessarily hold.

Comment: Yes, it is. As well as root and ratio test.

Comment: "Solutions manual developed by Roger Cooke of the University of Vermont", it's not from Rudin himself.

Comment: I would use Cauchy's convergence test, leveraging your remark that $(b_n)$ converges.

Comment: @root, your new proof scheme is right. You can use partial summation in my post to prove Theorem 3.42 too.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: For a counter-example to the first inequality in your first attempt, let $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}/n$ and $b_n=1$ for $n\ne 2$ and $b_2=2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer points out, if the $a_n$ don't all have the same sign, your inequalities don't necessarily hold. You should use partial summation (used in proving Abel theorem) to get an estimate of Cauchy sum.

Let $A_n=\sum_{k=m}^n a_k$. So by Cauchy Criterion, $|A_n|<\epsilon$ for $n,m>N$.

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m}^n a_kb_k&=\sum_{k=m}^n (A_k-A_{k-1})b_k
\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^n A_kb_k -\sum_{k=m}^n A_{k-1}b_k
\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} A_k(b_k-b_{k+1})+A_nb_n\tag{$A_{m−1}=0$}
\end{align}
First suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$ and $\:b_n \downarrow$. Then $\:b_n\geqslant0$, and $b_k-b_{k+1}\geqslant0\:$ for all $k>0$.

Since $-\epsilon<A_k<\epsilon$ for all $k>m$
$$
|A_k(b_k-b_{k+1})|<\epsilon(b_k-b_{k+1})
$$
So for all $n,m>N-1$, there is
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=m}^n a_kb_k\right|&\leqslant\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} |A_k(b_k-b_{k+1})|+|A_nb_n|
\\
&\leqslant\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} \epsilon\:(b_k-b_{k+1})+\epsilon \:b_n
\\
&=\epsilon \:(b_m-b_n+b_n)
\\
&=\epsilon \:b_m
\\
&\leqslant M\epsilon
\end{align}
So by Cauchy Criterion, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_kb_k$ converges.

Finally if $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=c\ne0$, we replace $b_n$ with $b_n-c$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_kb_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k(b_k-c)+c\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k 
$$
converges for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k(b_k-c)$ converges.